# Is it possible to tell closure compiler that 2 typedef intersect?

Tags: jsdoc, google-closure-compiler

I have a class for a model that contains a configuration, a plain object, with default values, and I want to create instances of this class by overriding only some of the configuration keys by passing another plain object, the options. I also want the code to work properly after being compiled in advanced mode and the keys of the configuration and options renamed.

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *     attribute1: string,
 *     attribute2: string,
 *     attribute3: string
 * }}
 */
let Params;

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *     attribute1: (string|undefined),
 *     attribute2: (string|undefined),
 *     attribute3: (string|undefined)
 * }}
 */
let Options;

class Model
{
    /**
     * @param {!Options=} options
     */
    constructor(options = {})
    {
        /** @private {!Params} */
        this.params = /** @type {!Params} */(Object.assign(this.getDefaults(), options));
    }

    /**
     * @return {!Params}
     */
    getDefaults()
    {
        return {
            attribute1: "default value 1",
            attribute2: "default value 2",
            attribute3: "default value 3",
        };
    }
}

/* Create a custom model by overriding only one attribute */
const model = new Model({
    attribute2: "custom value",
});
```

My problem is I don't know how to tell the compiler that types "Params" and "Options" shoud keep the same keys.
In advanced mode the properties will be renamed to something different.
For example `Params.attribute1` will become `Params.a` and `Options.attribute1` will become `Options.b` so I cannot merge them anymore.
Is there a way to make sure that the renamed properties still match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a working solution.
Seems like `@record` is a special type that automatically intersect any other type it can.
With the solution below type checking works and properties are renamed without breaking anything.

```
/** @record */
const Params = function() {};
/** @type {string} */Params.prototype.attribute1;
/** @type {string} */Params.prototype.attribute2;
/** @type {string} */Params.prototype.attribute3;

/** @record */
const Options = function() {};
/** @type {(string|undefined)} */Options.prototype.attribute1;
/** @type {(string|undefined)} */Options.prototype.attribute2;
/** @type {(string|undefined)} */Options.prototype.attribute3;

class Model
{
    /**
     * @param {!Options=} options
     */
    constructor(options = {})
    {
        /** @private {!Params} */
        this.params = /** @type {!Params} */(Object.assign(this.getDefaults(), options));
    }

    /**
     * @return {!Params}
     */
    getDefaults()
    {
        return {
            attribute1: "default value 1",
            attribute2: "default value 2",
            attribute3: "default value 3",
        };
    }
}

/* Create a custom model by overriding only one attribute */
const model = new Model({
    attribute2: "custom value",
});
```